# How to make token for exchange such as bittrex? I'm interested only in technical side of this question

Tags: exchanges, tokens

Should I set a starting price for the token? 
Is there a source code for the token for trading on the exchange?

Comment: There is a lot of tutorials and guides in the web, have you tried something?

Comment: @Зелёный yeah, a lot of guides, templates and others... but i can not understand some basics. so, on the offical website of the ethereum there are token templates, but they do not include the initial price of each token. I get a lot of source code of smart-contracts of the tokens on exchanges and they don't include the initial price too. There is no need for setting the initial price?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I set a starting price for the token?

It's depends what are you trying to achive with your token.

> There is no need for setting the initial price?

The initial price must be setted on contract creation.
Then with time it might adjusted while the token sale period.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard ERC20 code - https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol